# TeX capacity exceeded under Droit-fr 0.4

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently having a trouble with my Thesis on Latex.
I'm using [Droit-fr.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/droit-fr) and latexmk.

Here is my main console:

```
    Subroutine makeglo2gls redefined at (eval 8) line 19, <GEN1> chunk 1.
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 2 July 2013, version: 4.37.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.tex'
   Non-existent destination files:
      'main.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  --synctex=1 --file-line-error  -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droit-fr/droit-fr.cls
Document Class: droit-fr 2014/01/30 v0.4 classe pour droit francais
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2013/05/30 v3.7b configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem12.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mempatch.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifdraft.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/engrec/engrec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./main.ist'.



LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./main.gst'.


) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memhfixc.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bookmark.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bkm-pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droit-fr/droit-fr.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/verbose-ibid.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))

Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'related:default' already defined.
(biblatex)                Using \renewbibmacro.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droit-fr/droit-fr.cbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose-ibid.cbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)) (./bigcenter.sty)
Writing glossary file main.glo 
Writing index file auteurs.idx 

******************************************************
Stock height and width: 845.04684pt by 597.50787pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 845.04684pt by 597.50787pt
Text height and width: 641.80614pt by 448pt
Spine and edge margins: 59.73816pt and 89.63971pt
Upper and lower margins: 113.81102pt and 89.42969pt
Headheight and headsep: 14.5pt and 29pt
Footskip: 29pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 17pt and 51pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 92pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 92pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 14.5pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 590.14995pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 92pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 14.5pt and 590.14995pt
******************************************************

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/french.lbx)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [footnotereset=true,a4paper,12pt,twoside].

(./main.aux (./titre.aux) (./work.aux) (./F210.aux))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
(./main.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (./titre.tex
Overfull \hbox (4.0235pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--16
 [][] 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2])
No file work.tex.
(./F210.tex [1] [2]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'cass:req:19420128:set' on page 3 undefined on input li
ne 13.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'cass:req:19420128:set' on page 3 undefined on input li
ne 13.


Overfull \hbox (2.61961pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--13
[][][][]\T1/ptm/m/n/12 Chercher 

Overfull \hbox (2.61961pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--13
[][][][]\T1/ptm/m/n/12 Chercher 

Overfull \hbox (2.61961pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--13
[][][][]\T1/ptm/m/n/12 Chercher 

Overfull \hbox (2.61961pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--13
[][][][]\T1/ptm/m/n/12 Chercher 

Underfull \vbox (badness 3557) has occurred while \output is active [3]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'lenoir_les_1995' on page 4 undefined on input line 28.



LaTeX Warning: Citation 'sarvonat_principe_1951' on page 4 undefined on input l
ine 36.

[4]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'degoy_essai_2013' on page 5 undefined on input line 40
.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'domages_corps_1956' on page 5 undefined on input line 
40.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'picard_police_1984' on page 5 undefined on input line 
40.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'picard_police_1984' on page 5 undefined on input line 
41.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'degoy_essai_2013' on page 5 undefined on input line 43
.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'degoy_essai_2013' on page 5 undefined on input line 43
.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'henette_disposer_2004' on page 5 undefined on input li
ne 43.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'henette_disposer_2004' on page 5 undefined on input li
ne 43.


Overfull \hbox (13.78477pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 43--44
[]\T1/ptm/m/n/12 Le ca-rac-tère évo-lu-tif de l'ordre pu-blic cor-po-rel est au
ssi mis en va-leur par [][][][][]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'domages_corps_1956' on page 5 undefined on input line 
45.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [5]
Overfull \hbox (5.06851pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 57--58
[]\T1/ptm/m/n/12 L'influence des stoï-ciens va per-mettre d'adou-cir les meurs.
 Ci-cé-ron dé-cla-rait ^^S   nous sommes

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'domages_corps_1956' on page 6 undefined on input line 
59.

[6]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'cass:1civ:19830509:set' on page 7 undefined on input l
ine 73.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'levasseur_nouveau_1959' on page 7 undefined on input l
ine 75.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'mathieu_reconnaissance_1995' on page 7 undefined on in
put line 79.

[7]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'sarvonat_principe_1951' on page 8 undefined on input l
ine 83.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'memeteau_abordage_1994' on page 8 undefined on input l
ine 83.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'memeteau_abordage_1994' on page 8 undefined on input l
ine 83.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'terre_personnes_2012' on page 8 undefined on input lin
e 83.


Overfull \hbox (5.86136pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 83--85
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 ci-vi-li-sa-tion ju-ri-dique. C'est un ordre pu-blic su-pé-rieur
, ab-solu.[][][][]^^T Et []

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Rousseau_contrat_XXXX' on page 8 undefined on input li
ne 94.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Rousseau_contrat_XXXX' on page 8 undefined on input li
ne 94.

[8]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'tillet_droit_2004' on page 9 undefined on input line 9
9.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Kayser_droits_1971' on page 9 undefined on input line 
101.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Kayser_droits_1971' on page 9 undefined on input line 
101.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Hauser_ordre_repcivdalloz' on page 9 undefined on inpu
t line 103.


Underfull \hbox (badness 2245) in paragraph at lines 103--103
[][][]\T1/ptm/m/n/10 .[][]Les deux étant liés, l'in-vio-la-bi-lité im-pli-quant
 l'in-dis-po-ni-bi-lité et, par-tant, la non-patrimonialité.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Angevin_torture' on page 9 undefined on input line 108
.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'tillet_droit_2004' on page 9 undefined on input line 1
08.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Descombes_separer_2001' on page 9 undefined on input l
ine 108.

[9]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Carbonnier_civil1_2000' on page 10 undefined on input 
line 110.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'domages_corps_1956' on page 10 undefined on input line
 117.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thouvenin_construction_2001' on page 10 undefined on i
nput line 117.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thouvenin_construction_2001' on page 10 undefined on i
nput line 117.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Hauser_ordre_repcivdalloz' on page 10 undefined on inp
ut line 117.


Underfull \hbox (badness 1337) in paragraph at lines 117--117
[][][]\T1/ptm/m/n/10 .[][]Principe à re-voir se-lon cer-tains au-teurs, le lé-g
is-la-teur ayant al-lè-gre-ment confondu non pa-tri-mo-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2088) in paragraph at lines 117--117
\T1/ptm/m/n/10 nia-lité et non-commercialité, non-patrimonialité et gra-tuité e
t gra-tuité et don. Nous sui-vons en cela

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Kayser_droits_1971' on page 10 undefined on input line
 117.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Kayser_droits_1971' on page 10 undefined on input line
 117.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thouvenin_construction_2001' on page 10 undefined on i
nput line 117.

[10]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thouvenin_construction_2001' on page 11 undefined on i
nput line 120.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thouvenin_construction_2001' on page 11 undefined on i
nput line 120.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thouvenin_construction_2001' on page 11 undefined on i
nput line 120.


Overfull \hbox (122.00214pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 120--121
 \T1/ptm/b/n/10.95 19. L'ar-ti-cu-la-tion entre règles ci-viles et règles pé-na
les pro-té-geant l'in-té-grité.[] \T1/ptm/m/n/12 Se-lon []

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'fabre_responsabilite_2013' on page 11 undefined on inp
ut line 127.

[11]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'pradel_droitpenalspecial_2011' on page 12 undefined on
 input line 136.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'pradel_droitpenalspecial_2011' on page 12 undefined on
 input line 138.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'pradel_droitpenalspecial_2011' on page 12 undefined on
 input line 138.

[12]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'py_dimension_2013' on page 13 undefined on input line 
164.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'byk_progres_1994' on page 13 undefined on input line 1
71.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'byk_progres_1994' on page 13 undefined on input line 1
71.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'L95-116' on page 13 undefined on input line 173.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'kouchner' on page 13 undefined on input line 173.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bellivier_dimension_2013' on page 13 undefined on inpu
t line 175.

[13]
Overfull \hbox (0.61555pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 188--188
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 cherches 

Overfull \hbox (0.61555pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 188--188
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 cherches 

Overfull \hbox (0.61555pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 188--188
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 cherches 

Overfull \hbox (0.61555pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 188--188
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 cherches 

[...]


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hocquet_responsabilite_2006' on page 23 undefined on i
nput line 348.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hocquet_responsabilite_2006' on page 23 undefined on i
nput line 348.

./F210.tex:350: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\let \@xs@assign \@xs@expand@and@detokenize...
l.350 ...indexv{Autorisation de la loi}\citeauthor
                                                  {py_recherches_1993} voit ...

./F210.tex:350:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Index file 'auteurs.idx' was written
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main.bbl'
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'work.tex' from line
  'No file work.tex.'
Latexmk: Citation 'cass:req:19420128:set' on page 3 undefined 
Latexmk: Citation 'cass:req:19420128:set' on page 3 undefined 
[...]
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [main.bcf]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 193 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 256
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Thanks for your advices.

Clément

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While the log is useful for an investigation, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed for understanding what's going on.

Comment: It's hard to say but `./F210.tex:350: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a `  suggests that you do not need a bigger tex (It's quite hard to use up 5000 nested input levels) but rather that you have a fragile command expaning into an infinite loop it shows `\reserved@a` expanding into a definition involving `\reserved@a` so probably will just spin and fill up however many stack levels you have. Without seeing more code can't really say how you got in that position

Comment: the question is tagged biblatex but it looks like it is a problem with the (unshown) index command before the `\citeauthor` on line 350

Comment: It looks to me like this could be an issue with the `droit-fr` class itself. I do not know its exact inner workings, but you could perhaps try to reproduce the problem with a shorter document (try removing as much stuff as possible while getting the error) – this MWE would be useful here, but you could also send it along with the log to the developer (Yves).

Comment: Hi evry one! I have solved the problem. I've tried David's solution, but it's not a document size. It was a problem with the \verset{} title (witch is endemic to droit-fr). This title does not support the \emph{} command. The solution is to write {\em blabla}. Thanks a lot to all an specially to Yves (the developer)!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that cannot be reproduced from the question and has since been resolved (see comment above).